# Set iteration count

Tags: locust

I'm building a locust script to be integrated into our CI/CD pipeline as a synthetic monitoring solution. It'll run once, one iteration every 15 minutes. If the application fails alerts will be enabled and sent to the appropriate personnel.

Currently, I don't see any locust help with an iteration count command line option. I do see a --run-time option but that doesn't specify how many times it runs vs the amount of time to run.

Comment: Hi! See https://github.com/locustio/locust/issues/1085 Leave a comment if you want it to happen :)

Answer (score 0):

If you add `locust-plugins` there is now a way to do this, using command line parameter `-i`. See https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins#command-line-options